# Styling DataGrid SelectedRow in App.Config

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, app-config

I have a style in my `App.Config` that I am using to colour every `Rectangle` in my program;

```
<Style TargetType="Rectangle">
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Essentially I would like to do exactly the same, but change the colour of the highlighted row in my `DataGrid`. This is what I have attempted so far;

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="DataGridRow.IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

however this does not change the colour of the highlighted row, it is still the default colour in `WPF`. How can I program this into my `App.Config` so that the row colour changes?

Answer (score 1):

For that you will have to override the `SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey`. This is how you can do that

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
                   Color="Red"/>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```